# Подключение скачанной js библиотеки на страницу, в проекте на Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, node-modules

Не могу подключить  библиотеку leaflet.js на страницу проекта на Laravel, на [сайте leaflet'a](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/download.html) написано, что нужно вставить вот эти вот конструкции и указать путь

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/leaflet.css" /> 
<script src="/path/to/leaflet.js"></script>
```

сама библиотека скачана и находится в node_modules, просто указать путь не работает, нашел какую-то инфу про Laravel mix, но не помогло, или делал что-то не так

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы качаете с npm/yarn, то подключайте через import и компилируйте бандл. Если как в инструкции - качайте файлы напрямую, загружайте в public и подключайте в шаблоне Blade.